# Does CURL destroy session?

Tags: php, session, curl

My form is like :

```
<?php session_start();
// some variables
// entry into database with these variables 
//then using curl to post those data to external site.
//and then refresh to  another admin.php file after return curl.
```

in admin.php file.

```
//set up session key to a db value
// check. if false return to login page
```

But when refresh to admin.php then session is not working. return me to login page. 
But before curl add all process was ok.

So my question is : Does `curl` function destroy session ? If yes, then should i start the `session_start()` function after curl return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl does not affect your cookies or session in any way. If you're getting logged out, something else is causing the problem - possibly your database update?

It can be a bit confusing because curl *can* be configured too deal with cookies, but those are between your script and the site you're posting to with curl - and they're entirely separate from the cookies that are set between your visitor's browser and your script.

If you need help debugging the fact that you're getting logged out, please post a bit more code, including exactly what you added to make it stop working.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. curl won't destroy the session.